What kind of design tools are used in DevOps
I used to work on a project where I used CI/CD and docs-as-code for architecture design. It took me quite some time to change my way of thinking from the licensed tools I had before. I was kind of shocked at first to see that they were using things like PlantUML for UML whereas I was used to Enterprise Architect. I wanted to know more about DevOps design practices but I don't find much information on this subject. I usually see large tooling landscapes that show Atlassian tools, and jenkins and other testing tools, but in the design realm, I haven't found much.
Can someone refer me to some explanation on DevOps in the context of software design like architecture or even detailed design?
